# Confusing Chapter - Eigenvectors of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I'm taking a first course in Linear Algebra. I'm using Linear Algebra and Its Applications - 5th Ed. by David C. Lay. Chapter 5.4 (Eigenvectors and Linear Transformations) has been a tough chapter to grasp. This is a diagram I pulled from the textbook that shows what I'm talking about:

[image: ![textbook diagram]

Also, here is a snapshot of my Professor's notes, which somehow made things even more confusing for me:

[image: [![Professor's Notes][2]][2])]

Can anyone describe what's going on here, or refer me to an alternate source for learning this chapter in particular?

Comment: Here is a hint of how the matrix for changing the bases is derived on chapter 4.7. Assume that C and B are 2-d space. Let vector space C be formed from standard bases. Now do a clockwise 90 degree rotation on C and name the new vector space B. Keep both coordinate systems on the same place (will aid your visual intuition). The bases of B are b1 = [0,-1], b2 = [1,0]. Take a vector x base B. Try to reason why you should do a clockwise rotation of 90 degree (to x relative B, or multiply x relative to B with a 90 degree transformation matrix) in order to get x base C.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a base $\mathcal{B} = (\mathbf{b}_1,\mathbf{b}_2,\cdots )$ for the space $V$, this means that given a vector $\mathbf{x}\in V$ we can always find a set of numbers $(r_1,r_2,\cdots)$ such that

$$
\mathbf{x} = r_1\mathbf{b}_1 + r_2\mathbf{b}_2 + \cdots
$$

The array with all the $r$'s is called the coordinates of $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathcal{B}$ and in the book you are following is denoted by $[\mathbf{x}]_\mathcal{B}$.

Same logic can be applied for a vector in the space $W$.

Now imagine a linear operator between $V$ and $W$, a bridge that allows you to transform the vector $\mathbf{x}\in V$ into a vector $\mathbf{y}\in W$, let us call that operator $T$

\begin{eqnarray}
T: V &\to& W\\
\mathbf{x} &\mapsto& T(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{y}
\end{eqnarray}

The question your teacher is trying to answer is how to find $\mathbf{y}$, or said in another words, what is the image of $\mathbf{x}$ under the transformation $T$, or how the coordinates will transform when you make the vector $\mathbf{x}$ go through the bridge. The answer is simple provided you know how to transform the vector of the basis under $T$, that is, if you know

$$
T(\mathbf{b}_{i}) 
$$

In this case

$$
T(\mathbf{x}) = T(r_1\mathbf{b}_1 + r_2\mathbf{b}_2 + \cdots ) = r_1 T(\mathbf{b}_1) + r_2T(\mathbf{b}_2) + \cdots
$$